# Android Exclusive Toggle Button

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I have an Activity where I wish to show up a mutually exclusive set of `ToggleButtons` this's the layout:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/camera_buttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/action_camera1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="@string/title_camera1"
        android:textOn="@string/title_camera1"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/action_camera2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="@string/title_camera2"
        android:textOn="@string/title_camera2"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/action_camera3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="@string/title_camera3"
        android:textOn="@string/title_camera3"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/action_camera4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textOff="@string/title_camera4"
        android:textOn="@string/title_camera4"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/action_quad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/title_quad"
        android:textOff="@string/title_quad"
        android:textOn="@string/title_quad"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Obviously they are not mutually exclusive and I hope this type of behaviour can be defined trough layout and not only by code.

I have also another question: what events can be used to manage the iteraction with this list of buttons? 
I'm doing it trough `onCheckedChange` event is it some more specific event to get the checked widget instead of drill down the whole set?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for https://github.com/nex3z/ToggleButtonGroup

Comment: @Aiapaec very nice but I'd like to use native Android `ToggleButtons`

Comment: You can't do that without implementing all the logic yourself. But why do you want to use toggles instead of radio buttons?

Comment: ok I got. @IulianPopescu  It's mainly a matter of layout anyway